# Visualstudio.com: Identity not verified

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, cryptography, azure-devops

Why when visiting our account on https://oursite.visualstudio.com does Chrome complain about the website's identity?

[image: Identity not verified]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the SSL certificate used by Microsoft doesn't have the Audit records that verify that the certificate was really handed out to the organisation claiming to be VisualStudio.com or Microsoft.

I don't know why Microsoft chose such a certificate, but it's not uncommon. I suspect it is because while the certificate is owned by Microsoft, the content on the site is not. Having an "identified as Microsoft" on the site, might lead people to conclude that any data served by the site is also coming from Microsoft. As VisualStudio.com can be used to create **your** repository with **your** content, Microsoft can hardly claim to own it or be the responsible party of it.

If google really decides to stop accepting certificates without the full ownership audit records, then I suspect that Microsoft will update the certificate in the future.

Answer (score 2):

We have addressed part of this in updating the certificate to use SHA 2 earlier this week. That results in a green padlock now. We are planning on replacing the cert with one with audit records, though I don't have a timeframe to share yet.